# Beginning and end of the string in Emacs regexps

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

What is the characters that indicate the beginning and the end of the *string* with newlines in it? I'm writing a trim function:

```
(defun trim (str)
  (if (string-match "^[[:space:]]*\\(.+?\\)[[:space:]]*$" str)
      (match-string 1 str)
      str))
```

But with a string like "first/nnext" (got from `shell-command-to-string`) it returns only the "first". Reference manual says:

> When matching a string instead of a buffer, ‘^’ matches at the beginning of the
>   string or after a newline character.

`\\'` and the left one are for beginning/end of a buffer, so it simply returns nothing from a string. Therefore, how to indicate the 'absolute' beginning of a string, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's `` \\` `` for beginning of buffer or string.  And `\\'` for end.  See [manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash)

However, I think the root of your confustion isn't the anchor.  The `[:space:]` char class matches different characters based on the current syntax table.  To reliably match a non-printing or printing character use `[:graph:]`.  See [char class](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes)

Also `.` won't match newlines.

E.g.

```
(let ((str " \n a\nbc \n "))
  (string-match "\\`[^[:graph:]]*\\(\\(?:.\\|\n\\)+?\\)[^[:graph:]]*\\'" str)
  (match-string 1 str))
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. However, `\\'[[:space:]]*\\(.+?\\)[[:space:]]*\\'` (with "\\`" in the beginning) returns the original string, not cutting off the `\n`s in the beginning and the end.

Comment: The problem isn't the anchor, it's your regexp.  [:space:] doesn't match newline.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: "‘[:space:]’ This matches any character that has whitespace syntax (see Syntax Class Table)." (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Char-Classes.html). "Syntax class: whitespace character ... Space, tab, newline and formfeed are classified as whitespace in almost all major modes." (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html#Syntax-Class-Table). Hope your answer will help in this situation.

Comment: hmmm.  uh Are you still unsatisfied with this answer?  "almost all major modes" makes it pretty clear.  Every major mode can define what it considers a white space with its syntax table.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'm just struggling with newlines *inside* the string. Both variants (space and graph) return only the first string. `(let ((str " \n ab\nc \n ")) (string-match "^[^[:graph:]]*\\(.+?\\)[^[:graph:]]*$" str) (match-string 1 str))`. Newlines in the beginning and in the end are cut off with `:space:` too (at least in the minibuffer). But the problem is how to cut off spaces and newlines in the beginning and in the end of the string that contains newline characters inside.

Comment: Nope not a bug.  A brain fart on my part.  "." doesn't match newline.  See my modified answer

Comment: The latest edit works just great. Thank you very much for your time!